# Don't allow '@' in a registerForm angular8

Tags: angular

In my situation I just want to not let '@' in the new pseudo.

```
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      pseudo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.pattern(/^\S*$/)]  ],
      birthDate: ['', [Validators.required, this.majorValidator()]],
      ...
    })
```

I would a pseudo which can get : letter, number, '_' and '$'

Thank you so much if you have the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex code  `^[0-9A-Za-z\_\$]+$/`

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9A-Za-z\_\$]+$/)
```

you may also drop your `Validators.minLength(4)` and use the following regex

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9A-Za-z\_\$]{4,}$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the regex to `/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]*$/`

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]*$/)
```

Comment: Thank you but my pseudo still valid when I add an @, I can't let it in a pseudo

Comment: @RaphaëlEtang-Salé please try with this `Validators.pattern(/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]*$/)`

Comment: @vli020 please remove `@` from your pattern

Comment: Post your response @AshotAleqsanyan

Comment: @RaphaëlEtang-Salé check this one as right answer he will remove `@` when he looks at the comments

Comment: @RaphaëlEtang-Salé if you need to allow to type `$` too, please replace your validator with this `Validators.pattern(/^[0-9a-zA-Z_\$]*$/)`

Comment: Thank you too @RaphaëlEtang-Salé. glad to help you.